# How to call XML Webservices in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services

I am trying to call web services in my asp.net application.
I got success in calling normal web service.
But Now I am trying to call xml web services in my web project.
I have try for this using xmlhttp but i didn't get success in this.
Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Are you trying to call the service from the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by *XML web service*. For example ASP.NET web services that use SOAP are also XML. Maybe you mean a POX service (Plain Old XML)? In this case you could use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to manually forge and send an HTTP request to a given resource and fetch the result.

Comment: I got the answer. Its using HttpWebRequest. Thank you for replaying